# Checking 0 vector in R

Tags: r

What is wrong in this function?
I need to return same vector as input, if all values are 0, else min-max normalized

```
normalize <- function(x) {
    if (all(x==0)) return x
    return((x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))
}
```

Comment: Why didn't you use `else` ?

Comment: I thought that was unnecessary

Comment: I guess `normalize <- function(x) {
    if (all(x==0)) x
    else ((x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)))
}`

Comment: Thanks @akrun
Also, I just got it. The problem in my way is - "return (x)" is correct instead of  "return x".

Is "return" redundant in R?

Comment: Yes, you don't need `return` as in other languages, but won't hurt if it is used.

Comment: you dont need else, you do need to use parentheses with `return()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem was just that you didn't use `()` in your return statement.

```
x <- as.numeric(c(0,0,1,0,0,1,100,0,0,1,-23))

normalizeX <- function(x) {
  if (all(x==0)) {
   return (x) 
  } else{
    m      <- min(x)
    ma     <- max(x)
    result <- ((x-m)/(ma-m))
    return (result)
  }
}

normalizeX(x)

[1] 0.1869919 0.1869919 0.1951220 0.1869919 0.1869919 0.1951220 1.0000000 0.1869919 0.1869919 0.1951220 0.0000000

x <- as.numeric(c(0,0,0)) 
normalizeX(x)
[1] 0 0 0
```

I added some other minor changes, like calling the function something that's not going to be masked by packages, and storing the intermediate values for easier debugging / analysis.